# Delete a dynamically created table row

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following table which I am adding rows dynamically:

```
<table id="tblItems" border=2>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th class="numeric">Price/Ea.</th>
                    <th class="numeric">Qty.</th>
                    <th class="numeric">Total</th>
                    <th class="numeric">Edit</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

As I add each row, the `i` counter adds to itself, so the first ID would be `itemEntry1`, `itemEntry2` and so forth...

Add/Edit button function:

```
$("#addToTable").click(function() {
        i++;
        var priceText = $("#spanPrice").text();
        var toRemove = 'Each: ';
        var priceEach = priceText.replace(toRemove,'');
        var rowId = "itemEntry" + i + "";
        var strRowEntry = '<tr id="itemEntry' + i + '"><td class="rowItem">' + $("#itemChoice option:selected").text() +'</td><td class="rowItem">' + priceEach + '</td><td class="rowItem">' + $("#quantity").val() + '</td><td class="rowItem">' + $("#price").val() + '</td><td class="rowItem"><a href="#" onclick="doThis(' + rowId + ');"><img class="deleteRow" src="edit.png" border="0" id="imgEdit" /></a></td></tr>';
        $('#tblItems tr:last').after(strRowEntry);
        $("#modalNew").hide();
        //alert(strRowEntry);
        //alert($("#loginBox").height() + " " + $("#loginBox").width());
    });

function doThis(p) {
    var values = $('#'+p.id+' td').map(function(i,c){ return $(c).text(); }).get();
    //alert(p.id);
    //alert(values);
    $("#modalUpdate .modal-content .copy #itemChoice").val(values[0]);
    $("#modalUpdate .modal-content .copy #spanPrice").text("Each: " + values[1]);
    $("#modalUpdate .modal-content .copy #quantity").val(values[2]);
    $("#modalUpdate .modal-content .copy #price").val(values[3]);
    $('#modalUpdate').toggle();
    $('#modalUpdate').center();
}
```

I display a popup where the user can delete the row from where the EDIT button was clicked. I am using the following code:

```
<input type="button" value="Delete Item" id="deleteItem">

$("#deleteItem").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("test");
        $("#tblItem").closest('tr').remove();
    });
```

It just adds a `#` at the end of the URL instead of showing the alert and deleting the row.

Here is a screenshot of a sample table created:

[image]

So if I click the edit button for the row with `Qty=11` it will open a popup and the `Delete Item` button will be shown to the user. When they click on it that row ONLY should be deleted.

ModalUpdate dialog:

```
<div id="modalUpdate">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Update Item in Your Shopping Cart</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="copy">
            <label>Item:</label>
            <select id="itemChoice">
                <option value="Wine" selected>Wine</option>
                <option value="Shot">Shot</option>
                <option value="Beer">Beer</option>
            </select>
            <br /><span id="spanPrice"></span><br /><br />

            <label>Quantity:</label>
            <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="10">

            <label>Price:</label>
            <input type="text" id="price" name="price" placeholder="$10.00">

        </div>
        <div class="cf footer">
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="cancelUpdate"><input type="button" value="Delete Item" id="deleteItem"><input type="button" value="Update Item" id="updateTable">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve what I am looking to do?

Comment: When you click on the `edit` button, as you create the dialog, you need to get the `id` and put it somewhere where the `dialog` code can access it. You need to provide the `click` handler for the edit button in your question.

Comment: yes please share the code that how popup getting called and as Jared Farrish said, we need to set parent tr id of edit button clicked and use same id when click on delete button.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question with the edit button function.

Comment: what is rowId in doThis(' + rowId + ')? Can we pass this or 'i'?

Comment: Please create a working http://jsfiddle.net demonstrating your working code. Why is `p` being passed into a function name `doThis()`? Where is the click handler on the edit button?

Comment: I am using `i` as a counter for each row... `i` starts off as `1` and so forth...

Comment: please share modalUpdate dialog html also, and is p.id is same as tr id ?

Comment: I updated my question with the ADD/EDIT function

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar Yes, it is the ID of that row.

Comment: Added the modal update HTML...

Comment: If it still doesn't help, I will create the JSFiddle.

Comment: Here is a basic demonstration of how I would suggest you go about it: http://jsfiddle.net/KdBds/1

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZV92Q/

Comment: Your fiddle is broken. Use the Javascript Console (F12) to inspect errors.

Comment: Ok this function was causing the error: `//$('#tblItems').on('click', '.deleteRow', function(e){ 
 // e.preventDefault(); // stops the page jumping to the top
  //$(this).closest('tr').remove();
 //});` which I commented out. Everything else is working now but when I click the DELETE button I get this message in the console window: `Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLTableRowElement] `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While setting values to popup, set `data-parent` to delete button in `doThis(p)` function :

```
function doThis(p) {
    var values = $('#'+p.id+' td').map(function(i,c){ return $(c).text(); }).get();
    //alert(p.id);
    //alert(values);
    $("#modalUpdate .modal-content .copy #itemChoice").val(values[0]);
    $("#modalUpdate .modal-content .copy #spanPrice").text("Each: " + values[1]);
    $("#modalUpdate .modal-content .copy #quantity").val(values[2]);
    $("#modalUpdate .modal-content .copy #price").val(values[3]);
    $("#deleteItem").attr('data-parent',p.id);// set id here (Edit: add the '.id' to the p
    $('#modalUpdate').toggle();
    $('#modalUpdate').center();
}
```

You can get parent `tr` of the delete button and remove it.

```
  $("#deleteItem").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("test");
        var parentTr = $(this).data('parent');
        $('#'+parentTr).closest('tr').remove();// change here
    });
```

Comment: It is a popup where the Delete button is shown, so I want to get the TR of the table that's on the page and not the popup.

Comment: If it's in a dialog window, that will not (typically) be inline with the `tr` it spawned from.

Comment: @SiKni8, can you please share how popup getting called, we can passed the parent tr id to popup and on click of delete button we can remove the tr.

Comment: Let me know if that works or not. You can just create an HTML page and see if it works for you and how I can fix it. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok this function was causing the error: `//$('#tblItems').on('click', '.deleteRow', function(e){ 
 // e.preventDefault(); // stops the page jumping to the top
  //$(this).closest('tr').remove();
 //});` which I commented out. Everything else is working now but when I click the DELETE button I get this message in the console window: `Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLTableRowElement] `